# Can I use a Kotlin Contract to guarantee the non-nullity of another property?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-experimental

I have a class with a nullable property `description: String?`, and for convenience would like to expose a `fun hasDescription(): Boolean` that null-checks said String.

For even more convenience, I am hoping to use a contract so I can smart cast `description` to non-nullable `String` after checking `hasDescription()`.

1. Is this possible now (with experimental contracts, and Kotlin 1.5)?
2. Might it be possible when contracts go stable?

```
data class Widget (
    val description: String? = null,
)


class Gadget {
    val widget: Widget? = null

    val description: String? get() = widget?.description

    @ExperimentalContracts
    fun hasDescription(): Boolean {
        // Error in contract description: only references to
        // parameters are allowed in contract description
        contract {
            returns(true) implies((this@Gadget).description is String)
        }

        return this.description != null
    }
}

@ExperimentalContracts
fun testContract(gadget: Gadget) {
    if (gadget.hasDescription()) {
        // Error: Type mismatch (String? for String)
        // expected, since the contract itself does not compile
        val description: String = gadget.description
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be possible, but smart casts of other class's `val` properties don't work if the other class is in a different module. Not sure if tests behave as if in another module in this case. Thanks, @broot for correcting me in the comments of my now-deleted answer.

Answer (score 3):

In short, it's not possible.

> Contracts primarily consider the **behavior of methods** rather than the properties of values. Properties of values should be handled by the type system rather than contracts.

And yes, it might be implemented in the future.

> It doesn't mean that if something potentially can be handled by the type system, then it is out of contracts' scope.

https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/kotlin-contracts.md#scope-and-restrictions

#### Alternatives

Nulls are well handled in Kotlin's type system, and so we can use that to check for nullability.

###### Smart casting

Using smart-casting would remove the need for Contracts and the `hasDescription()`
method.

```kotlin
fun nullCheckWhen(gadget: Gadget) {
  when (val description = gadget.description) {
    null -> println("description is null")
    else -> println("description.length ${description.length}")
  }
}
```

```kotlin
fun earlyReturn(gadget: Gadget) {
  val description = gadget.description ?: return

  println("description.length ${description.length}")
}
```

```kotlin
fun forcefulNullCheck(gadget: Gadget) {

  val description = requireNotNull(gadget.description) {
    "description must not be null"
  }

  println("description.length ${description.length}")
}
```

```kotlin
fun elvisScopeFunctionNullSafe(gadget: Gadget) {

  gadget.widget?.description?.let { description ->
    println("description.length ${description.length}")
  }

}
```

These are a little more clunky, and not as pretty as Contracts could be - but at least they work.

In fact, some of them use Kotlin Contracts, but of course they can only work on method parameters.

[`Preconditions.kt`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/771eff503bba150ad7f223d3a26bf111ad0ad7fc/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Preconditions.kt#L46)

```kotlin
/**
 * Throws an [IllegalArgumentException] if the [value] is null. Otherwise returns the not null value.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T : Any> requireNotNull(value: T?): T {
  contract {
    returns() implies (value != null)
  }
  return requireNotNull(value) { "Required value was null." }
}
```

##### Type hierarchies

I don't think this approach is applicable to your situation, but I thought I'd share it as it can be useful.

If `description` was defined in an interface as a `String?`, then `Widget` could implement `description` as a non-nullable `String`. This works because in Kotlin the nullable type is a super-type of the non-nullable type. Any implementation of `description` can choose to be either be `String?` or `String`.

```kotlin
interface Component {
  val description: String?
}


data class Widget(
  override val description: String
) : Component


data class Greeble(
  override val description: String?
) : Component


fun nullCheckGeneric(component: Component) {

  when (component) {
    is Widget  ->
      // no need for a null check
      println("description.length ${component.description.length}")
    is Greeble ->
      // description is nullable
      println("description.length ${component.description?.length}")
  }

}
```